# Interpolated Ruby within a method call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On my user model, I have a bunch of attributes like is_foos_admin and is_bars_admin that determine which kinds of records a user is allowed to edit.

I'd like to DRY out my edit links, which currently look like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_foo_path(foo), :class => 'edit' if current_user.is_foos_admin? %>
...
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_bar_path(bar), :class => 'edit' if current_user.is_bars_admin? %>
```

I want to make a helper that lets me pass in a foo or bar and get back a link to edit it, like so:

`<%= edit_link_for(foo) %>`

The helper might look like this *(which doesn't work)*:

```
def edit_link_for(thing)
  if current_user.is_things_admin?
    link_to 'Edit', edit_polymorphic_path(thing), :class => 'edit'
  end
end
```

The model-agnostic edit_polymorphic_path method gets me halfway there, but it's the "is_things_admin" method that I don't know how to universalize. If I could use interpolated Ruby inside of a helper, I'd want to do something like

```
if current_user.is_#{thing.class.name.downcase.pluralize}_admin?
```

But of course that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using `send`:

```
if current_user.send("is_#{@model}_admin?")
```

Comment: send() does the trick precisely! The conditional line of my helper becomes `if current_user.send("is_#{thing.class.table_name}_admin?")`